# Create face with k vertices CGAL c++

Tags: c++, c++11, cgal

I'm working on a project to display and interact with object loaded. I load .obj files, but in some of them i have faces with like 10 vertices, i've searched but i didn't find how to create face like that with CGAL. I tried to use this : https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedron__incremental__builder__3.html#a4d6b47abdda805ccc6142ecbe78002c7 but without success, can someone help me pls ?

Comment: Pleaae add your code

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the incremental builder. In this [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2polyhedron_prog_incr_builder_8cpp-example.html), if you call more than three times `B.add_vertex_to_facet(k)` then your face will contain more that 3 vertices.

Alternatively, the function [`CGAL::Euler::add_face()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLEulerOperations.html#gaa386d0cdef3b5d6ef43d6b503392dbcd) is also available and has a simpler API. Note that the range provided to the function must be the range of vertices of the face (added using `CGAL::add_vertex()` for example).